# GRPC streaming not working when forwarded via Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http2, grpc

I have a gRPC service and I want to deploy it behind an Apache reverse proxy.

The apache configuration is similar to the following:

```
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
...
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ServerName service.mydomain.com:443
  SSLCertificateFile ".../mycert.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ".../mycert.key"
    
  ProxyPass / h2c://localhost:5048/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5048/

</VirtualHost>
```

The unary RPC-s works fine. But I want to use bidirectional calls. These calls never end, after timeout I get an error.

I made several attempts by increasing the timeout and the like, without success.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives to the following

```
ProxyPass "/" "h2://localhost:5048/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "h2://localhost:5048/"
```

you may also need to adjust the `Timeout` and `ProxyTimeout` directives to ensure that the requests have enough time to complete. You can try increasing these values to see if it improves the behavior.

```
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
```